# Set Foreign Key with Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I am newby in Programming and Database work. I have question with Foreign key related.

I have two tables in sql server 2008. CallDetails,PageDetails.

**For Example**
PageDetails Table.

```
    PageId PageLoadTime PageUnloadTime
       1      12:00PM         1:00PM
       2      1:00PM          2:00PM
       3      2:00PM          3:00PM
```

CallDetails Table

```
    CallId CallStartTime CallEndTime
      1       12:05PM       12:10PM
      2       12:15PM       12:25PM
      3       02:35PM       02:40PM
```

Now I want one more Cloumn as PageId in CallDetaiuls Table where CallId time should be between PageDetails time duration. Like, CallId 1 has PageId 1 ,CallId 2 has PageId 1,CallId3 has PageId 3.

I know Ican do this with giving foreign key to CallDetails Table But How can I give condition as above for assigning Foreign Key????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key only enforce that value in column PageId in CallDetails must occur in PageDetails table. For all other logic you can use for example:

*CHECK CONSTRAINTS(Not useful in your case)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

*DML TRIGGERS (for more complicated logic, comparing with data from another table etc.)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx
*Your own logic in application.

In this case I would use trigger. And also if you have one, another logic on the application side.

Comment: Thank you, I got my answer I implement my where condition in insert statement....Its working and getting right pageID. But still I am searching for good answer so your link will be helpfull to me thank you